# Query on session clear on logout

Tags: php, session, browser, safari, logout

We are encountering a situation where on multiple login - logouts, we reach a specific point where the previous session data is used while logging in. In other words on logout total session closing/clear is not occurring.

We are using both session_destroy and session_unset functions in the code on logout. It all works fine unless we have successive login- logouts.

We are  having session destroy issues on mobile safari iOS 9.x, i it helps.

Would be great if you could guide us on this. Thank You

Comment: Please find below the code:

Comment: // ajax
function fuseLogout() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: API.FUSE + "logout",
        success: function (data) {
            location.href = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/pos/login";
        },
        error:function (data) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}

Comment: // server side.
function logout_post() {
     $data4 = array('emp_session' => '', 'emp_role' => '', 'device_location_id' => '');
        $this->session->unset_userdata($data4);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
 $this->response('Success', 200);
    }